# Image button not changing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, button

I'm trying to change the image of 25 buttons sequentially with delayed time between the changes and it doesn't work.

The code is:

```
do {
    if (Anterior > -1) {
        [[BtnArray objectAtIndex(Anterior)] setImage:Nil];
    }
    [[BtnArray objectAtIndex:(Gira[J])]
       setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Encen.png"]];
    Anterior = Gira[J];
    Delay(Espera,&junk);
    ++J;
} while (J<25);
```

Comment: What is `Anterior`, `Gira`, `Delay()`, `Espera`, `junk`? "_It doesn't work_" is not enough. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The delay or the image change? How is the Delay() function implemented?

Comment: If your `Delay()` is just a call to `sleep`, it won't work. `sleep` is blocking, and the UI must wait for the whole `do {} while ()` loop to terminate before it can be updated.

Comment: Anterior is a integer to set "off" then last image button. Gira is a Integer Array to control what button will set their image "On". Delay(), I think, is a objective-c command to delaying time between different actions. Espera is a long set the delay time between On and Off image button. junk is a long to complete the parameters of delay command. The image button don't change. Only the Delay time work fine.

Comment: Ok Cyrille, then how I can do this? Somebody can answer me?

Comment: There's no "Delay()" in Objective-C... It must be implemented elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not tested, but you could try something like this:

```
float delay = .2;
for (UIButton *btn in btnArray) {
    [btn performSelector:@selector(setImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Encen.png"] afterDelay:delay];
    delay += .2;
}
```

Or in place of calling on btn have your own function

```
float delay = .2;
for (UIButton *btn in btnArray) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(changeImageForButton:) withObject:btn afterDelay:delay];
    delay += .2;
}
```

then in that function do:

```
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Encen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks, but the program continues running when the delay occurs and the effect I need not be shown

Comment: oh, you want to block the main thread? If so you can try sleep(delay);

Comment: I tried with sleep(timedelay) but the computer goes to sleep...XD... this app is for mac not for iphone.